# Regular expression to match an empty string?

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I want to match and group any of these listed words:

`aboutus/`,`race/`,`cruise/`,`westerlies/`,`weather/`,`reach/`,`gear/` or `empty_string`

Here is a solution, but which will not match the empty_string:

```
^(aboutus|race|cruise|westerlies|weather|reach|gear)/$
```

So my question is: **How to include Empty string in this matching?**

I still don't get a good solution for this.

So I added one more regex specially for empty_string:ie `^$`.

Note: these regular expression is for django `urls.py`.

**update:** It will be better if the capturing group does not contain `/`

Comment: wouldn't `^(aboutus|race|cruise|westerlies|weather|reach|gear|)/$` work?

Comment: How about `^(aboutus|race|cruise|westerlies|weather|reach|gear)?/$`

Comment: Will the empty string still be followed by a `/`?

Comment: @njzk2 no. it won't work.

Comment: @Drewness no `/`. empty string is purely empty. I am using it in django urls.py, so it is similar to `^$`

Comment: There was a flaw in my first answer. Now it's corrected and it works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this

```
^$|^(aboutus|race|cruise|westerlies|weather|reach|gear)/$
```

Comment: It would be better to place ``^$`` at the end, like that ``...gear)/$|^$`` because I suppose that in the majority of cases, the tested string won't be empty, then if ``^$`` is in second place, the first part of the alternation will immediately produce the good result; the part ``^$`` won't be verified on each tested string.

Answer (score 8):

try this:

```
^(aboutus|race|cruise|westerlies|weather|reach|gear)?/$
```

edit:
if '/' is in every case except the empty string try this

```
^((aboutus|race|cruise|westerlies|weather|reach|gear)(/))?$
```

Comment: This is the best correct solution. The `?` means 0 or 1 occurrence which is exactly the OP's goal.

Comment: sorry `aboutus/` is required. i updated the question. but empty string is purely empty

Comment: then try this

^(aboutus/|race/|cruise/|westerlies/|weather/|reach/|gear/)?$

Comment: @omair_77 thanks omar `?` really helped me a lots... :)

Comment: You mean `(?<=^aboutus\/)(?:race|cruise|westerlies|weather|reach|gear)?$`? This would capture anything after "aboutus/", including nothing.

Comment: @omair_77 it will be helpful if the capturing group doesn't contain `/`

Answer (score 1):

You can make the capturing group optional:

```
^(aboutus|race|cruise|westerlies|weather|reach|gear)?/$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

rgx = re.compile('^((aboutus|race|cruise|westerlies'
                 '|weather|reach|gear)/|)$')

# or

li = ['aboutus','race','cruise','westerlies',
      'weather','reach','gear']
rgx = re.compile('^((%s)/|)$' % '|'.join(li))


for s  in ('aboutus/',
           'westerlies/',
           'westerlies/ ',
           ''):
    m = rgx.search(s)
    print '%-21r%r' % (s,rgx.search(s).group() if m else m)
```

result

```
'aboutus/'           'aboutus/'
'westerlies/'        'westerlies/'
'westerlies/ '       None
''                   ''
```